# Can you use GitHub Secrets in application.yaml or can it only be used in the Workflow file?

Tags: yaml, github-secret

I want to store DB credentials in GitHub secrets. Wondering if they can be used like so:

```
 datasource:
    url: db_name
    username: ${{ secrets.username }}
    password: ${{ secrets.password }}
```

Or will the secrets only work in the workflow files? Is there a way to get the secrets into my application.yaml file?

Comment: Only in the workflow file, GitHub Actions doesn't search your whole codebase for `${{ ... }}` to replace. If you want those values accessible, expose them via env vars: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv